# destructor called when failing to create the instance?

Tags: python-3.x, garbage-collection, destructor, instantiation

When trying to understand some Python concepts, I encountered the following problem :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __del__(self):
        print("del")

a1 = A()
```

outputs :

```
$ python test.py
del
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testdest.py", line 9, in <module>
    a1 = A()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The error is obvious (missing argument when instantiating), but I wonder **why the destructor is called before having an instance?**

Unless that when trying to instantiate, Python creates a sort of instance even before calling the constructor and that will need to be cleaned at the end?

Since `self` is passed to the constructor, Can I assume this `self` is the instance? It that's true, then the instance already exists when calling the constructor, is that right?

Is this a behaviour of the garbage collector that may depend of the current implementation?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I usually think of `__del__` as similar to a `finally` clause, i.e. something that is executed "no matter what".

Comment: @Kris Kind of. There is no guarantee, though, that `__del__` will be called for instances that are still live when the interpreter exits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Python documentation:

> Objects are never explicitly destroyed; however, when they become
>   unreachable they may be garbage-collected. An implementation is
>   allowed to postpone garbage collection or omit it altogether — it is a
>   matter of implementation quality how garbage collection is
>   implemented, as long as no objects are collected that are still
>   reachable.
>
> ```
> object.__init__(self[, ...])
> ```
>
> Called after the instance has been created (by **new**()),
>   but before it is returned to the caller. [...]
>
> ```
> object.__del__(self)
> ```
>
> Called when the instance is about to be destroyed. [...]

So the object instance already exists when `__init__` is called, as it is created by `__new__`. But for Python in general, there is no guarantee that `__del__` will ever be called.

The following only applies to CPython, the reference implementation of Python.

> Note (for `object.__del__(self)`)
>
> del x doesn’t directly `call x.__del__()` — the former decrements the 
>   reference count for x by one, and the latter is only called when x‘s
>   reference count reaches zero. [...]

Here `__del__` is called whenever the reference count for the instance drops to 0. This has nothing to do with garbage collection. A little experiment:

```
>>> class A:
...   def __del__(self): print "del"
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a = None
del
>>> import gc
>>> gc.disable() 
>>> a = A()
>>> a = None
del
```

As you can see, the destructor is called even when GC is explicitly disabled.

Note that this also implies that if you have cycles in your object hierarchy, you end up with objects for which `__del__` never gets called, as the Python GC can't deal with reference cycles.

```
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a2 = A()
>>> a1.x = a2
>>> a2.x = a1
>>> a1 = None
>>> a2 = None
>>> import gc
>>> gc.collect()
4
>>> gc.garbage
[<__main__.A instance at 0x7f2c66a1d7e8>, <__main__.A instance at 0x7f2c66a1d830>]
```

Comment: *"And `__del__` is called whenever the reference count for the instance drops to 0."* ...and the Garbage Collector runs over it. *When* this happens depends on the algorithm used by the Python interpreter, which differs from implementation to implementation. In extreme cases, it may even not happen at all until the entire program exits.

Comment: @Markus I find your answer very interesting but I just need an explanation about your last sentence I don't fully understand : *"whenever the reference count for the instance drops to 0."*. I may say something stupid, but does that mean *"whenever the instance isn't assigned to a variable anymore."*?

Comment: @vmonteco Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Markus I switched to the python3 doc version but I think it does, thank you! :)

Comment: @vmonteco I added a ittle example for when `__del__` will never be called.

Comment: @markus Python does not use reference counting. *CPython* (the reference implementation of Python) uses reference counting. In CPython, the del method is called unconditionally when it's reference count reaches 0. However, the garbage collector exists to handle cases where the object is unreachable, but has a positive reference count (cyclical references).